# Active Choices Reactive Parameter Groovy script to read artifact from another job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

- What I am trying to achieve:

I have a job A which results in an artifact. The artifact is called "result.json"

[image]

Here is a sample of the result.json

```
[
  {
    "product": "banana",
    "from": "India",
    "price": "42"
  },
  {
    "product": "coconut",
    "from": "Thailand",
    "price": "1"
  },
  {
    "product": "Watermelon",
    "from": "Japan",
    "price": "1000"
  },
  {
    "product": "orange",
    "color": "Spain",
    "price": "5"
  }
]
```

Please note, result.json is not a static file. The content changes on each build.

I have a job B, where I would like to create a parameter list, list from the "result.json" file from pipeline A.

Basically, to create active choices reactive parameters using groovy script.

- Expected result:

With the code below, I would have expected the parameters to be populated.

[image]

- Actual result:

Unfortunately, there is no entry, it seems like job B is not able to pick the "result.json" from job A.

A screenshot of what I am seeing so far is:

[image]

- What I tried:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def filedata = readFile(file: 'jobA.result.json')

def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()
def data = jsonParser.parseText(filedata)
return data.fullName
```

- Question:

I am sure the "result.json" is there from job A.

How to get the file from job B, in the Active Choices Reactive Parameter Groovy script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a parameter list in job B from the "`result.json`" artifact produced by job A, you will need to make sure job B can access the artifact stored by job A.
That means "`result.json`" must be archived in job A and is accessible, with a `'jobA.result.json'` correctly points to the archived artifact from job A. And job B must have permissions to access artifacts from job A.

```bash
Job A   ┌─────────┐   result.json  ┌─────────┐   Job B
───────>│ Archive │───────────────>│ Read &  │───────>
        │ Artifact│<───────────────│ Parse   │<───────
        └─────────┘   Accessible?  └─────────┘
```

You can use in the [Active Choices Reactive Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) feature in your Groovy script.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import hudson.FilePath
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def jobA = jenkins.getItem("JobA")
def lastSuccessfulBuild = jobA.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
def artifact = lastSuccessfulBuild.getArtifactManager().root().child("result.json")
def filedata = new FilePath(artifact).readToString()

def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()
def data = jsonParser.parseText(filedata)

// Assuming you want to create a string in the format "product-from-price"
def parameters = data.collect { "${it.product}-${it.from}-${it.price}" }
return parameters
```

That script is meant to run within the [Jenkins script console](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-console/), or as part of a job configured with script permissions.

---

> Small pure technical issue, with the stack trace below:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 900eeb7f-97e8-40c3-8c1a-d65af18d917a groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException:
Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.FilePath(jenkins.util.VirtualFile$FileVF) 
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1742) 
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1549) 
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:48)
```

The error is caused by an incorrect attempt to create a [`hudson.FilePath`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/FilePath.html) object with an instance of [`jenkins.util.VirtualFile`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/util/VirtualFile.html), which is not a valid argument for any of the constructors listed in the `FilePath` class.

To fix the issue, you should not create a `FilePath` directly from a `VirtualFile`. Instead, you should be using the appropriate methods provided by the `VirtualFile` API to read the contents.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.BufferedReader

def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def jobA = jenkins.getItem("JobA")
def lastSuccessfulBuild = jobA.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
def artifact = lastSuccessfulBuild.getArtifactManager().root().child("result.json")

def fileInputStream = artifact.open()
def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8"))
def filedata = reader.lines().collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining("\n"))
reader.close()

def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()
def data = jsonParser.parseText(filedata)

// Assuming you want to create a string in the format "product-from-price"
def parameters = data.collect { "${it.product}-${it.from}-${it.price}" }
return parameters
```

If `artifact` is indeed a `VirtualFile`, then you can use the [`open()` method](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/util/VirtualFile.html#open()) to get an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html?is-external=true).

If `artifact` is not a `VirtualFile`, and is instead a `String` representing a file path, you would need to use the appropriate `FilePath` constructor that matches your scenario. For example, if you have a remote file path, you would use the constructor with a [`VirtualChannel`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/component/remoting/hudson/remoting/VirtualChannel.html) and a `String`. If you have a `File` object representing a local path, you would use the constructor that accepts a `File` object.

The script provided assumes you are working within Jenkins' pipeline and have the correct permissions set up. Make sure to check [Jenkins' script approval](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/) if you have permissions issues.

---

> I am now able to get the json inside jobB.
> Unfortunately, there is still another technical issue, the dropdown appears only as `[object Object]`.

If the dropdown displays `[object Object]` instead of the expected string values, that should mean you try to directly display objects in the UI without converting them to strings. The UI is interpreting the list of objects as an array of object literals, and `[object Object]` is the default string representation of an object in JavaScript.

In the context of a Jenkins Active Choices Reactive Parameter, the `return` statement should return a list of strings that represent the choices to be displayed in the dropdown. If you are returning objects or a complex data structure, you should map them to a string representation first.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.BufferedReader

def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def jobA = jenkins.getItem("JobA")
def lastSuccessfulBuild = jobA.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
def artifact = lastSuccessfulBuild.getArtifactManager().root().child("result.json")

def fileInputStream = artifact.open()
def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "UTF-8"))
def filedata = reader.lines().collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.joining("\n"))
reader.close()

def jsonParser = new JsonSlurper()
def data = jsonParser.parseText(filedata)

// Map the objects to a string representation, for example "product-from-price"
def parameters = data.collect { "${it.product}-${it.from}-${it.price}" }

// Make sure the return is a list of strings
return parameters
```

Here, `parameters` should be a list of strings, each string being a concatenation of the product, its origin, and its price, separated by dashes. Make sure this format matches what you want to display in the dropdown.
If `data` is not a list but a map or a single object, you will need to adjust the `collect` closure to fit the actual structure of your JSON.

Comment: Hello @VonC, the answer is clear, easy to understand and well written. With that said, I am facing a small pure technical issue, therefore, I will attach the stack trace below. Could you please have a look? Thank you in advanced

Comment: ```
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 900eeb7f-97e8-40c3-8c1a-d65af18d917a
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.FilePath(jenkins.util.VirtualFile$FileVF)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1742)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1549)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:48)
```

Comment: Hello @VonC, your edit is very helpful. I am now able to get the json inside jobB. Would like to thank you for that already. Unfortunately, there is still another technical issue, the dropdown appears only as ```[object Object]```. I attached another screenshot in my original question. Would you know the technical root cause of this?

Comment: @PatPanda OK, I have edited the answer to address your last comment.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. The answer is very clear. Upvote + accept + award